# Conditionally change order of if-else blocks

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there an elegant way to solve this?

```
if (condition0) {
  if(condition1) {
    do thing 1
  }
  else if(condition2){
    do thing 2
  }
}
else {
  if(condition2) {
    do thing 2
  }
  else if(condition1){
    do thing 1
  }
}
```

`do thing 1` and `do thing 2` function calls with a lot of parameters and somehow it seems like there is unnecessary repetition.

Is there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (condition1 && (condition0 || !condition2)) {
  do thing 1
} else if (condition2) {
  do thing 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In the industry , would people like it if I did this, or the normal way?

Comment: I guess it depends on how complex the conditions are vs. the complexity of "do things". In general, you try to avoid redundancy: People may find an error in "do thing 1" and then forget to update the second call...

Comment: If the conditions are complex, and have no side-effects, consider testing them all together and storing them in very well-named boolean variables - that will make Stefan's code a lot easier to read than long conditions

Comment: I've checked - this is the shortest form possible. +1

  @tucuxi: this would be helpful for some (including me), however it might be a waste of variables and could be considered as "noise" in the code.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repetition of code, you could store do thing 1 and do thing 2 in functions. To make it clean.

```
var DoThing1 = function ()
{
   do thing 1
}

var DoThing2 = function ()
{
    do thing 2
}
if (condition0) {
    if(condition1) {
        DoThing1();
    }
    else if(condition2){
        DoThing2();
    }
}
else {
    if(condition2) {
        DoThing2(); 
    }
    else if(condition1){
        DoThing1();
    }
}
```